# C++, can't assign a new value to dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, hash, hashmap

I'm trying to write a hash table implementation of map, and I'm running into some error that crashes the program when I try to run it - specifically when I try to put new values into the map. This is the put function:

```
template<class KEY,class T, int (*thash)(const KEY& a)>
T HashMap<KEY,T,thash>::put(const KEY& key, const T& value) {
    int hash_index = hash_compress(key);
    LN* key_ln = find_key(hash_index,key);
    if (key_ln != nullptr){
        T to_return = (key_ln->value).second;
        (key_ln->value).second = value;
        return to_return;
    }

    this->ensure_load_threshold(used+1);
    hash_index = hash_compress(key);
    //map[hash_index] = new LN(Entry(key,value),map[hash_index]);
    ++mod_count;
    ++used;
    return value;
}
```

The problem line is the one that's commented out. When this line is not there, the test program is able to run put fine (it just, obviously, doesn't add anything). What it SHOULD do is allocate space for a new Linked Node in a linked list with the next node being the current linked node which map at hash_index points to, and with the linked node's value being the Entry type object which is just a pair of the key and values.

It doesn't do that. It crashes the program. However, it ONLY does this when I tell it to change the value to something it's not currently. When I say:

```
map[hash_index] = new LN();
```

it works fine; that is how each index is initialized, so this does not really change much. All of the fields in the LN() constructor seem to be without a problem too, as this works:

```
LN* new_ln = new LN(Entry(key,value),map[hash_index]);
std::cout << new_ln->value.first;
```

The problem is also not in the hash_compress function which derives the index to change, as this doesn't work either:

map[0] = new LN(Entry(key,value),map[0]);

And it definitely has an index at 0. The only thing that doesn't work is assigning new values to an array index.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `new LN();` *is* a new value, since it's a different node to the one that was already there.

Comment: Hmm. Then I guess it crashes only when I assign it anything other than a blank LN?

Comment: If you separate it into two lines: `LN *new_ln = new LN(Entry(key,value), map[hash_index]); map[hash_index]=new_ln;` then which one crashes?

Comment: What is the value of hash_index when it crashes? (Use a debugger, or print it between the two lines)

Comment: hash_index is zero. bins is set to 1 by default, and hash_index is obtained as the remainder of the hash over the number of bins.
    `hash_index: 0`